# como conectar dropbox si no puedo abrir el navegador?

Tags: linux, archlinux

Soy nuevo en Arch
Intento instalar dropbox en mi pc con arch linux, pero no logro llegar al login. Aparece el applet, pero al momento de apretar en Sign In no sucede nada. Imagino que es porque no puede acceder a alguna variable de entorno que le diga cual es el navegador que usar.
No creo que sea error de instalacion, porque lo instale con yay, manualmente desde el AUR y con wget como dice en la pagina https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux pero con todo llego al mismo resultado.
No se donde encontrar los logs de dropbox
Dejo esto por si sirve:

```
[sg@sg ~]$ ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
dropbox: locating interpreter
dropbox: logging to /tmp/dropbox-antifreeze-VNcFt2
dropbox: initializing
dropbox: initializing python 3.8.7
dropbox: setting program path '/home/sg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-118.4.460/dropbox'
dropbox: setting python path '/home/sg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-118.4.460:/home/sg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-118.4.460/python-packages.zip'
dropbox: python initialized
dropbox: running dropbox
dropbox: setting args
dropbox: enabling allocator metrics
dropbox: applying overrides
dropbox: running main script
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/sg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-118.4.460/cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/sg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-118.4.460/cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/sg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-118.4.460/psutil._psutil_linux.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/sg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-118.4.460/psutil._psutil_posix.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/sg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-118.4.460/apex._apex.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/sg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-118.4.460/tornado.speedups.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/sg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-118.4.460/wrapt._wrappers.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/sg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-118.4.460/PyQt5.QtWidgets.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/sg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-118.4.460/PyQt5.QtCore.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/sg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-118.4.460/PyQt5.QtGui.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/sg/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-118.4.460/PyQt5.QtDBus.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo acabo de solucionar con el [script de python](https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py) de https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux
Lo controlo solo desde la terminal y me dio el enlace que copie de la terminal y pegue en el navegador para conectarlo.